# I had installed pillow but I can't use makemigrations command and it tell me pillow is not installed

Tags: django, powershell, terminal, pip, python-imaging-library

this is my problem:

```
PS C:\Users\mydesktop\trydjango19> py -2 manage.py makemigrations
```

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS:
>   posts.Post.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
>           HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".
>   PS C:\Users\mydesktop\trydjango19> pip install pillow
>   Collecting pillow
>     Using cached Pillow-3.4.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
>   Installing collected packages: pillow
>   Successfully installed pillow-3.4.2
>   PS C:\Users\mydesktop\trydjango19> py -2 manage.py makemigrations
>   SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS:
>   posts.Post.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
>           HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".
>   PS C:\Users\Rich Family\trydjango19>

Comment: Have you installed pillow in the same virtual environment as one you are using to run Django?

Comment: Thanks @AlexVyushkov

Comment: Yes that was my problem!